# Python 'Screen' output

Tags: python

I use the `screen` module of Python so I can have multiple shells run on my server while my laptop is vast asleep.

However, when the scripts are done I need have quite a lot of information to print which simply requires me to scroll through it.

With Python in command prompt on a windows machine this is not a problem. 
Using the `Screen` Module however does not allow me to do this.

So can I add some code that makes the `Screen` output scrollable?

Comment: tie the output to a variable and then pipe it to a text file if you need an example I can provide one.

Comment: It's a valid solution, thanks. No need for an example.
Just wish there was something wouldn't require this.